# Vuex как правильно редактировать объект в состоянии полученного через геттер?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

В базе данных есть таблицы с иерархичной структурой, где в таблице присутствует поле parentId, что бы в дальнейшем строить дерево. Бек на фронт возвращает данные в виде списка, для того что бы фронту не пришлось бегать рекурсивной функцией в поисках нужного объекта, всякий раз когда пользователь будет с ним осуществлять какие либо действия. Ленивая загрузка данных мне не подходит, по этому приходится грузить все необходимые данные в интерфейс для их редактирования.

На фронте есть Vuex с кучей модулей, каждый из которых работает с определённый таблицей и один общий модуль страницы, на которой осуществляется редактирование всех этих таблиц.

Структура модулей такова:

```
root (Vuex.store)
-> workspace
-> -> table1
-> -> table2
-> -> ...
```

Все модули-таблицы содержат одно состояние (states) со списком данных пришедших с бека, состояние естественно обновляется через мутации (mutations), по типу `loadAll, add, update, remove`. Мутации вызывается исключительно через действия (actions) где есть некий ApiRepository который шлёт запрос в бек с определёнными параметрами и выполняет чтение или редактирование данных. После успешного чтения или редактирования (CRUD) вызывается соответствующая мутация и данные обновляются.

Параллельно с изменением данных в модуле tableN, мутируются состояния модуля workspace, где есть условно состояния `tableNTree: Node[]` и `tableNMap: Map<number, Node>`. Тут свой собственный набор мутаций, для гибкой работы с деревом. Далее приложение работает исключительно с этими данными.

В модуле workspace есть getter `tree: state => state.tableNTree`. Теперь когда меняется этот геттер, мой компонент строит дерево. Когда пользователь жмакнет элемент дерева (ноду), будет вызвано действие "workspace/select", изменится дополнительное состояние и построится подходящая карточка с полями (input, select, multi form и прочие компоненты для изменения данных).

Проблема в том, что я пытаюсь редактировать геттер

```
{
  template: `
   <MyBigForm v-if="selected !== null" v-model="selected"></MyBigForm>
  `,
  computed: {
    selected (): Node | null {
      return this.$store.getters['workspace/selected'];
    }
  }
}
```

У computed свойств, есть возможность использовать get и set. В get мы дёргаем геттер хранилища, а в set мы выполняем действие для обновления данных, но везде примеры только с типами данными `string`, `number`, `boolean` и как правило один `input` прикрепят и вуаля, получите и распишитесь. Также находил на этом портале решения, когда мы следим за каждым свойством объекта (в моем случае Node), но что если их там 20 и есть ещё какие то произвольные JSON данные в одном поле, зависящие от выбранного типа (поле table1.type ENUM, и поле table1.properties JSON). Мне получается нужно через `this.$watch` динамически строить слежку за каждым свойством моего объекта, и каждое его изменение выполнять какое то динамическое действие по типу `this.$store.actions('workspace/table1/update', { id, propName, value })`, так ещё где `propName` может быть значение `'properties.childProp'` что дополнительно нужно парсить и тд. Это вообще не удобно и дополнительно нагружает интерфейс.

Но если этого не делать и обновлять объект из геттера, то vuex обратно вернёт все значения. Есть вариант сделать клон объекта, в моём случае объект это класс, где можно сделать метод `Node.clone()` и именного результат метода уже кидать в компонент-форму через директиву v-model. Дальше например банально, юзер нажал кнопку `Сохранить` и на базе клонированного объекта построился `payload` для отправки в `dispatch`.

Vuex мне нужен для того что бы:

1. Упорядочить все данные
2. Трансформировать данные
3. Прикрепить два Vuex плагина, первый для авто сохранения данных, второй для undo/redo (ctrl+z и ctrl+shift+z).

Словили подходящую мутацию, задали отложенный таймер на сохранение и дополнительно сохранили клон объекта в историю изменений.

**Посоветуйте пожалуйста что-то годное. Это может быть что угодно, в контексте вопроса. Спасибо.**

Comment: А почему не получается в computed -> set написать нужную логику сохранения?